# What is the texture used in this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

Could someone tell me what is the texture used in this image (Venue and Time portion of the image)?

[image]

https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/52035/screenshots/576187/new-dribbble.png

I'm guessing it could be a paper texture. But would like to know for sure.
Please help.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Looks like a paper texture.

Comment: Questions on this site [should not depend on links](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2807/19174), so they can help future visitors even in case of link rot. Please include the relevant images into your question, if this is possible copyright-wise.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a generic paper texture pattern with the opacity and saturation fiddled with. I would check out http://subtlepatterns.com/ and pick one that looks similar!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like wrought iron patterns to me, repeated across. Search Google for "wrought iron fence patterns" and you will find something similar. Then you can apply them in the background at low opacity levels. Something like this comes to my mind, make up your preferred pattern.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for not reading the question.